# Cannot type in output panel in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, java.util.scanner

I try Scanner method from Java, but when I debug in NetBeans, the output panel does not show me anything and same problem with typing into output panel to test the Scanner method.
Does anyone, how to fix it ?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class HowToUseScanner {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println(" What is your name ? ");
        System.out.println("Input =>");
        String name = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("My name is "  + name + ".");
    }

}
```

[Picture of Netbeans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAyBj.png)

Comment: Could you please paste your code here.

Comment: First, Show me your code

Comment: Your above code works well

Comment: Yeh it works. Could you provide us with screen?

Comment: Yes, it build successful. But do not show me the questions, what I wrote in System.out.println().

Comment: Problem is, that it my case it does show everything " What is your name ? 
Input => <user_input> etc.

Comment: Update the link on the picture

Comment: @user3770144 Try right click your class file eg: HowToUseScanner.java from Pokusy_Java project then click Run File.

Comment: @user3770144 Working or not?? right click HowToUseScanner.java then click Run File

Comment: I tried it and not, but I made a new project and insert the same code and it has worked in the new project.

Comment: Could be the problem, that I have to many main classes in one package ?

Comment: I think yup, your Pokusy_java project got too many main class. When you try to run the project, it will choose one of the main classes(eg: Losovac.java) to run.

Comment: btw how many main classes do u have in that Pokusy_java project?

Comment: I have there three main classes, so that is the root of the problem.

Comment: @user3770144 to find out try to put System.out.println("Testing1"); on each main method classes with different value eg: testing2, testing3 then run that project. see the output from console